Show that the error in this Galerkin approximation satisfies the "orthogonality condition".
This question is paraphrased from page 14 of Finite Elements: An Introduction Volume 1 (Becker, Cary, Oden). Concatenating functions will be the Hadamard product (matching, element-wise multiplication of image points), rather than composition.

Question: The variational form of our problem is equivalent to $$\int \limits_0^1 (-u'' + u)v \,dx = \int \limits_0^1 xv \, dx $$
Where $u$ and $v$ are garden variety trial and test functions; they vanish on the endpoints of the unit interval and have square-integrable first derivatives. Assume also that their second derivatives exist.
Let $u_N$ and $v_N$ be the Galerkin approximations of these functions by some $N$ basis functions for each. Similarly, both of these Galerkin approximations are defined on the unit interval, have square-integrable first derivatives, have second derivatives, and vanish at the endpoints. Show that the error $e = u - u_N$ in the Galerkin approximation staisfies the "orthogonality condition," $$\int \limits_0^1 (e' v'_N + e v_N)dx = 0 $$

Answer: The strong form of the solution will satisfy our weak formulation. This means that $$\int \limits_0^1\left(u' v_N' + u \, v_N \right) = \int \limits_0^1\left(u'_N v_N' + u_N  v_N \right)$$
Because our function $v_N$ vanishes at the endpoints, we can flip signs and transfer derivatives to obtain:
$$\int \limits_0^1 (e' v_N' + e v_N)dx  = \int \limits_0^1  v_N(e - e'')  dx= \int \limits_0^1 \left( v_N(u - u_N) - v_N(u'' - u''_N) \right)dx $$
Now let's re-arrange our terms and distribute the integral to obtain:
$$ \int \limits_0^1 \ v_N(u - u'') dx - \int \limits_0^1 v_N(u_N - u''_N) dx = \int \limits_0^1\left(u' v_N' + u \, v_N \right)dx - \int \limits_0^1\left(u'_N v_N' + u_N  v_N \right)dx = 0$$

Is my statement about the strong form satisfying the weak form like this correct? It holds in the idealized variational sense, but I don't know if the Galerkin method is preserving the total area obtained by the integral when it breaks things down into shape functions. However, I wasn't able to find any way to solve this otherwise. Let me know if/why it holds, and if not give a better proof.

There is not need to perform integration by parts. In fact, those second derivatives $u_N''$ most likely do not exist (for eg piecewise linear finite elements). Instead, test the weak formulation for $u$ and $u_N$ with $v_n$ and subtract. The proof is a one-liner.
